# restarting service remotely via snmp blocked by selinux/pam on Redhat8

Tags: rhel, pam, selinux, snmp

I am having some trouble remotely starting/stopping/restarting a service through snmp.

It seems to work fine with SElinux set in permissive but with it in enforcing mode it will fail with this type of error message (as seen in /var/log/secure)

```
Aug 17 15:29:43 tester2-RHEL8 sudo: PAM audit_log_acct_message() failed: Permission denied
Aug 17 15:29:43 tester2-RHEL8 sudo:  testuser : PAM account management error: Permission denied ; TTY=unknown ; PWD=/ ; USER=root ; COMMAND=/sbin/service router stop
```

That message in itself is pretty useless

In /var/log/messages the commands seem to be executed sucessfully

```
Aug 17 15:29:43 tester2-RHEL8 snmpd[1501]: RTRSnmp : stopping RTR service
Aug 17 15:29:43 tester2-RHEL8 snmpd[1501]: RTRSnmp : starting external process "sudo service router stop &" as user testuser
Aug 17 15:29:43 tester2-RHEL8 snmpd[1501]: RTRSnmp : external process "sudo service router stop &" exited with status 0
```

Here is the snmpd.conf file

```
###########################################################################
snmpd.conf

###########################################################################
# SECTION: Access Control Setup

# SNMP v1 and v2
rocommunity public
rwcommunity testuser

# SNMP v3
createUser testuser SHA testusersnmp
rouser testuser

createUser testuserrw SHA testusersnmp
rwuser testuserrw

###########################################################################
# SECTION: Trap Destinations

trapcommunity trapdest
trap2sink 127.0.0.1 testdir

doNotRetainNotificationLogs yes

###########################################################################
# SECTION: System Information Setup

syslocation s-RTR
syscontact info@xxxxxxx.com

###########################################################################
# SECTION: RTR SNMP Module

dlmod S_RTR /home/testuser/release/release_1/bin/libRTRSnmpAgent.so

rtr_ip 127.0.0.1
rtr_port 4500
rtr_retry_period 10
rtr_end_system_id 000000000
rtr_service_user testuser
rtr_service_start sudo service router start
rtr_service_stop sudo service router stop &
rtr_service_restart sudo service router restart &
```

Having become quite fed up I ended up also just removing the silent denials with

```
semodule -DB
```

This also proved to be unsuccessful, even when adding selinux policies based on the suggestions in sealert

I have since created clean install and I am now back at the above permission denied error with little to no clue what is the underlying cause other than the fact that SElinux has a problem with this command remotely via snmp:

```
snmpset -v3 -u testuserrw -l authNoPriv -a SHA -x AES -A password -X password 192.168.0.122 "0.0.0.0.0.0.40140.0.0.0.0.0" i 0
```

The same commands will work over ssh for further info.

I'm at a loss as to where I can go from here, even some information on how to increase logging would be a great help as I don't see anything about it in the redhat documentation.

### Cheers,

Comment: The important information should be in /var/log/audit/ . Anyway it's probably about allowing a transition from a process type to an other process type. More difficult than just dealing with files.

Comment: It will also work when you only set the snmpd_t domain to permissive while the rest of the system is in enforcing. `sudo semanage permissive -a snmpd_t`